# Can't find ADP login page password box by webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, adp

I want to download report from ADP platform through webdriver, but I can't locate the login page password box.
Can anyone help me, thanks a lot!
Blow is my part code:

```
print("start to login")
chrome.get('https://online.adp.com/signin/v1/?APPID=WFNPortal&productId=80e309c3-7085-bae1-e053-3505430b5495&returnURL=https://workforcenow.adp.com/&callingAppId=WFN&TARGET=-SM-https://workforcenow.adp.com/theme/unified.html')
wait.until(lambda x: x.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'input'))
user_name=chrome.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login-form_username"]')
user_name.send_keys('phenix.gao')

wait.until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.ID, "verifUseridBtn"))
chrome.find_element(By.ID, "verifUseridBtn").click()

print("input ps")
time.sleep(3)
# wait.until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="login-form_password"]'))
# wait.until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.ID, "login-form_password"))
chrome.find_element(By.ID, "login-form_password").send_keys('123')

print("click login button")
wait.until(lambda x: x.find_elements(By.ID,'signBtn'))
chrome.find_element(By.ID,'signBtn').click()

wait.until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@title="Dashboards"]'))
print("login success")
```

[ADP login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhq8q.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8xLP.png)

I try to find it by XPATH and ID, and also add wait code, but none of them worked.
Moreover, it is not in ifame.

Answer (score 0):

The selector seems ok. I think the problem is in the application. When running the test the application shows an error when next button is clicked.

```
(By.ID, "login-form_password")
```

You can try with this as well:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-form_password"))
```

The easiest way to wait for the elements is to set implicit wait:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! I tried it your way, but it didn't work. 
I suspect what defense mechanism does the ADP platform have, like some hidden fields or something else, but I can't figure it out.